# Selenium not able to click link

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to use Selenium in python 3.6 to click on a link, but I keep getting the same error. I have pip installed selenium and am using this code in Aptana

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\noart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\noart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\noart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\noart\Desktop\Exercize Files Beginner\Ch2\Drivers_Ed_Made_Easy.py", line 4, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\noart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\noart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: We are going to need the HTML and the call you are making to declare the element to be clicked before being able to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Seems that you don't set the executable path of the geckodriver.

Try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'\yourPathTo\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.co.uk/")
```

Comment: Hi there! I'm still getting this error with this renewed code

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\noart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\noart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\noart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\noart\Desktop\Exercize Files Beginner\Ch2\Drivers_Ed_Made_Easy.py", line 4, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\noart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.service.start()

Comment: File "C:\Users\noart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: Ignore this -- Thanks

Comment: @NoahRatliff Happy to help.